# ResourceNotFoundException for existing DynamoDB table

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314386/simple-dynamodb-request-failing-with-resourcenotfoundexception) question on the topic, but it doesn't help (see below).

I have a DDB Table `my_table` in `eu-west-1`, which I can (successfully) scan from my EC2 (same region, with `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` attached to its IAM) instance with AWS CLI:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_table --region eu-west-1
```

This is the Java model that I've created:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="my_table")
public class TableModel {
  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "partition_key")
  private final Long partitionKey;
  // ...
}
```

And this is how I query it (code executed from same EC2):

```
public class DDBQuery {
    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
    public DDBQuery() {
        dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build());
    }
    public void scan() {
        final List<DRTFacet> result = dynamoDBMapper.scan(TableModel.class, new DynamoDBScanExpression()); // Exception!
    } 
}
```

However, I get the title exception. 
**Note:** vars have been renaming for sake of simplicity and confidentiality.

Comment: I can only suggest to review AWS credential provider chain to ensure you don't have any wrongly configured env or system variable: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-default

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite surprised to find out that the root error was because I the annotation in the actual class was of the type:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName=MyConstantsClass.TABLE_NAME)
```

That damned `MyConstantsClass.` generated the error.

As soon as I refactored this into:

```
//Appropriate import for TABLE_NAME
@DynamoDBTable(tableName=TABLE_NAME)
```

The error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

it's either you don't have a Table with that name or it is in CREATING status . This info from awsdocs . But I think , you missed to add attributes DynamoDbcScannExpression. You might need to add some attributes like :

DynamoDBScanExpression dynamoDBScanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
            .withFilterExpression("#timestamp < :from")
            .withExpressionAttributeNames(attributeNames)
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(attributeValues);

```
List<Login> logins = dynamoDBMapper.scan(Login.class, dynamoDBScanExpression);

return logins;
```